# Heading in javascript or html in a component-based design for website

Tags: javascript, html, css, directory-structure

I like the component based method of creating different folders for different components.
So I currently have:

```
- components/
  - heading/
    - heading.css
    - heading.js
    - heading.html
```

I want my html to look like the code below for the heading (includes both bootstrap and custom css classes):

```
<body>
    <div class="container text-white">
        <div class="position-relative pb-5">
            <h1 class="position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x display-1">HEADING</h1>
        </div>
</body>
```

How do I achieve this? Should I import this `html` into `js` (I am using webpack) or should I add these classes manually in `js` after creating and appending the two `div`s to the body?
I know the second option is tedious but I don't think the first option will make the heading reusable for other pages. Is there a better way that I have not mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to answer because what can be "the better way" depend of your project and what you are targeting to do with.
But i think that you start coding, so you maybe want to import your Javascript code inside your html heading.html page, and same for your css file (using Bootstrap is not an obligation, if you learn something, use CSS directly should be better and efficient).
Webpack will just follow what you do and the way you will setup it to do to provide one or any bundled files to use by your server. It is not related to your project the way you configure it. I mean, you can just build your project and care about webpack at the end or directly configure Webpack and go for your project (if you want some splited files for CSS you can also config Webpack for that, and also for dynamic update of your bundle's files.But this has nothing to do with your question.
If your question is "how to import a html file (let's said: the header's one) inside the main one", then you can do it from Javascript code. You can then select the html tag for that, or use an id.
As i told you, for me it is difficult to help you more with vague question, because it can be many different way to practice to be "the best way" (and also "best" can be an opinion).
Hope this would help you a bit.